# How to delete sms backup?

Tags: sms, backup, messaging

I recently upgraded to a Lumia 950 on windows 10 (previously had a Nokia 930 on windows 8.1). I noticed my backed up text messages were duplicated and sometimes tripled on my new phone which causes the messaging app to run very very slowly. I have the messages backed up locally on my PC but restoring from this using contacts+message backup seems to just add more copies of the messages.

I have attempted to delete the messages in the messaging app but this causes the app to crash and not open until I perform a factory reset. This then triggers the phone to download all the backed up messages again. So I am stuck in a loop.

Is there a way to delete the online sms backup so I can use the local backup. Or can I force the online backup to take the image of the sms on my old phone so they download correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue. Follow these steps to solve this problem and use online backup again

1. Go to [Onedrive website](https://onedrive.live.com/)
2. Log into your MS account and go to Options.
3. Click on Device Backups.
4. Delete the backups associated with the device you are using.(This will delete backup)
5. In your phone, Disconnect the internet, delete all your messages and take a backup using an app such as Contact+messages backup or Transfer my Data.
6. Reset your phone.
7. Now import messages via the same app used for backup.
8. Turn ON internet backup again.
9. It should work fine now.

In case if you don't want to backup online anymore, follow these steps.

1. Sign out of messaging app and turn off SMS backup in settings.
2. Delete all conversations and import it via the contacts+messages app.
3. Use this app to create local backups manually.

Comment: Thank-you for such a fast answer. I will try this. However when I try to delete a few conversations on my phone the messaging app crashes ( I imagine due to the large volume of sms its trying to download) after this the app does not open unless i factory reset which starts the process again.

Comment: Seems like you have to do a factory reset one last time after deleting the backup online.
Did you try to delete just a single or just a few hand selected messages? Does the app crash in this case too?

Comment: @ThisWillDoIt Yeah, I tried that. In my case, it just created another copy of all other messages (really wierd). Even deleting all my SMS in phone resulted in downloading all these SMS from my backup. Somehow the process will not sync the changes in phone to Backup but it will only sync down from the cloud.